# why the fancybox cannot work in my octopress blog?

Tags: ruby, fancybox, blogs, octopress

As the title said, the fancybox cannot work well in my octopress blog?
My github project URL: https://github.com/tinyxd/tinyxd.github.com
My blog url : http://tinyxd.me

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot work well"? What specific problems are you getting? Have you looked at the Javascript error console?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the privilege to comment yet, but I want you to try this: http://www.forceappx.com/blog/2011/12/28/getting-fancybox-to-play-nice-with-octopress/